# NativeScript actionItem alignment

Tags: nativescript

I have a NativeScript application with the ActionBar like the following image.

How can I force the ActionItem (3 bars icon) to be on the right side instead of the left side?
The problem is that on Android 10 and above, when device language is Hebrew (RTL language) the ActionItem is on the left and I would like to keep it right.

[image: NativeScript actionItem]

Comment: What's your code to generate the action items, and what type of project are you using (i.e., JavaScript, Angular, Vue)?

Comment: I am using Angular

Answer (score 0):

To align items inside the actionbar to the right, use:

```
<ActionBar title="HBreader">
    <ActionItem
        ios.position="right"
        android.position="actionBar"
        (tap)="doThisAndThat()"
    >
        // your view element here (image/icon/label/etc...)
    </ActionItem>
</ActionBar>
```

Comment: On Android 10 and above when set to RTL language (such as Hebrew) it moves to the right and I would like to keep it on the left.

Comment: Android only or Android and iOS?

Comment: In Android, you can force disabling RTL by changing property supportRtl="false" in your AndroidManifest.xml file.